# Need to return production finish date of an order based on the weekly production Qty in excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 tables 
Table-1 = Order details
Table-2 = Production details.

Explanation of color inside table:
Yellow color = Output Qty week wise and product wise.
Green color = My expectation. Example- The second order of shirt(Qty-10) delivery date is 14 Jan & there are 2 more orders (order num 1 & 4) of shirt which have delivery earlier than 14 Jan. So the finish week will be 4 as the order num 1 & 4 (total Qty 6) will be produced till week 2 as per the Table-2 (total  Qty =7 (3+4).

Thanks to help me write the formula in E 2 to E6 cells.

Table1:

[image: Table-1]

Table2:

[image: Table-2]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Work out the sum of quantities for the same product and dates including this one using sumifs.

Compare it to the cumulative sum of the numbers produced for this product using match.

```
=ArrayFormula(match(true,sumifs(C$2:C$6,B$2:B$6,B2,D$2:D$6,"<="&D2)<=sumif(column(H:K),"<="&column(H:K),index(H$3:K$4,match(B2,G$3:G$4,0),0)),0))
```

[image]

I'm assuming for the time being that you couldn't have two rows with the same product and delivery date. If this could happen, you could refine the formula for the situation where (say) the first delivery could be sent in week 2 but the next delivery would be in week 3.

Comment: Sorry i replied to you without login to Stack overflow